# Problem to use accuracy score in multi-label problem in python

Tags: python, multilabel-classification

I am trying to evaluate my model prediction. What I have is the following:

- My `y_test` is a `1489x13` data frame
- My `predictions` is a `<1489x13 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>' with 11166 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Column format>`

When I try to calculate accuracy, I get the following:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(y_test, predictions)

TypeError: len() of unsized object
```

When I tried to change the type of the data (as I saw from other questions):

```
accuracy_score(np.array(y_test), predictions.A)

ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

Another attempt:

```
accuracy_score(y_test,predictions.A)
ValueError: multiclass-multioutput is not supported
```

May I know what can I do?

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error when you do `accuracy_score(y_test, predictions.A)` ?

Comment: Included in the question. It did not work. I was following [this tutorial](https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff). It worked in the data of the article that has the same type of mine. I don't know what is wrong with mine.